# Excel VBA - multiple filters on pivot table: one linked to filter other pivot table; one based on the cell I just clicked on in a selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compose a report that makes a pivot table based on location and product.
The location filter should be the same as the filter of another pivot table on that worksheet (however, I cannot use slicers as the dataset is not the same).
The product filter should change depending on which cell I just clicked on in a certain range.

I have tried quite a lot of stuff found on different fora and have adjusted to my needs, but seems to me the problem is that I need a private sub SelectionChange in order to dynamically change the product. However I would need a PivotTableUpdate private sub for the location filter. Can't have both on one sheet right? So how to deal with these cases?
The code I am using for the productfilter is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    If Target.Column = 13 Then
        Range("M2").Value = Target.Value

    End If
End Sub
```

This is basically copying the value from the clicked cell in column 13 to cell M2, which is the cell for my pivottable filter. Additional issue is that if I click on a cell which does not provide a valid filter entry, I get an error. How to solve that?

Comment: If both pivottables share the same pivotcache, simply create a slicer for each filterfield, which you tie to both pivottables. The slicers can be on any (hidden) sheet but will ensure the filters are in synch.

Comment: that's the thing. The 2 pivot tables do not use the same data

Answer (score 0):

If both pivottables are on the same sheet and have one page filter, it can be as easy as adding this to the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.PageRange.Column <> Sh.PivotTables(1).PageRange.Column Then
        Sh.PivotTables(1).PageRange.Cells(1, 2).Value = Target.PageRange.Cells(1, 2).Value
    Else
        Sh.PivotTables(2).PageRange.Cells(1, 2).Value = Target.PageRange.Cells(1, 2).Value
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```